# How to use EF7 from VSCode in Mac?

Tags: c#, postgresql, visual-studio-code, entity-framework-core

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to connect to a DB preferably PostgreSQL (or do I must use MS SQL?). How do I do that in VSCode and Mac (using dnx CLI)?

Comment: You can use PostgreSQL via nPgSQL.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**
There is an official guide to getting setup in OS X. It uses SQLite, but switching out providers shouldn't be too tough.

http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/osx.html

**Original answer**

If you want to use VS Code, you need to setup your project using ASP.NET 5. [See this guide for doing the initial project setup](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/ASPnet5).

You can use `EntityFramework.SQLite` or `Npgsql.EntityFramework7` on OS X. To use these, add them to your `project.json` file. Both are **pre-release, unstable builds** and require that you use their myget.org feeds. To do this, add a [Nuget.config file](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-file) to your project.

This is my Nuget.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
      <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
      <add key="AspNextVNext" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2" />
      <add key="Npgsql" value="https://www.myget.org/F/npgsql-unstable/api/v2" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What kind of using statement should I use?

Comment: And how do I connect to a postgres server?

Comment: @naterncmaster http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31064306/npsql-entityframework7-cannot-use-npgsql-server

Answer (score 0):

If all you are looking for is a connection string then see: [PostgreSQL connections strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql/)

For an example on how to do it in C#, see the example at:
[Using PostgreSQL in your C# (.NET) application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30989/Using-PostgreSQL-in-your-C-NET-application-An-intr)

Other than that, you would need to post your code that you have tried to be able to offer any further assistance. Otherwise, this is too broad a question to help.