# Npsql.EntityFramework7 cannot use npgsql server

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm pretty new to C#. I'm getting some red squiggles(error underlines) on `.UseNpgsql(string connectionString)` below. The hovering error tells me that I'm probably not using the right using statement.

```
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;

namespace Something.Context {

    public class OauthTokenContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Model.OauthToken> OauthTokens { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
        {
            var connectionString = @"Server=localhost; Port=1337; User Id=tinganho; Password=secret; Database=hello";
            builder.UseNpgsql(connectionString);
        }
    }
}
```

In my `project.json` I have the following dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Npgsql.EntityFramework7": "3.1.0-unstable0038",
    "Npgsql": "3.1.0-unstable0038"
}
```

And in `startup.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
using Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Routing;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
using Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection;

using Npgsql;
using Npgsql.EntityFramework7;

using Something.Context;
using Something.Model;

namespace Something
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
        }

        // This method gets called by a runtime.
        // Use this method to add services to the container
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddEntityFramework()
                .AddDbContext<OauthTokenContext>();

            services.AddMvc();
            // Uncomment the following line to add Web API services which makes it easier to port Web API 2 controllers.
            // You will also need to add the Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim package to the 'dependencies' section of project.json.
            // services.AddWebApiConventions();
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

        // Configure is called after ConfigureServices is called.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            // Add MVC to the request pipeline.
            app.UseMvc();
            // Add the following route for porting Web API 2 controllers.
            // routes.MapWebApiRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id?}");
        }
    }
}
```

And when I add `.AddNpgsql()` after `services.AddEntityFramework()` I get:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.Abstractions' or one of its dependencies
```

Comment: First, the Npgsql EF7 provider is pretty far from being usable even in non-production - it's truly WIP at the moment.

Having said that, you should be getting basic things up and running. For the specific errors above, try to take a look at Npgsql.EntityFramework7.FunctionalTests for some examples, especially, say, TransactionNpgsqlFixture. For the UseNpgsql issue please post a full compilation error.

Comment: I think the name has changed to EntityFramework7.Npgsql - this fits with the naming convention of another database provider where EntityFramework7 was first, followed by the specific provider afterwards. Not posting as an answer because I'm not totally sure.

Answer (score 2):

You should use this approach:

1) into **Startup.ConfigureServices** add only **services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()**;

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
        //...
        services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql();
}
```

2) into class inherit the **DbContext**:

```
public class DatabaseClass : DbContext 
{
    //...

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("my connection string");
    }
}
```